# App Runner health check fails when connecting RDS

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk, amazon-app-runner

I am trying to spin up an AppRunner service that connects with a private RDS instance. The idea is to keep the App runner service public, but the DB is in a private VPC. I created VPC connector within same VPC, but when the app runner service runs, it shows the error as:

```
health check on port 80 failed. Service is rolling back. Check your configured port number.
```

Even the application logs are not generated. It seems like I have some incorrect network configurations, but not able to figure that out.

I am sure that the port number & docker container is doing fine because I tried running locally and it worked *(was connected to a public RDS)*

Here is my CDK code:

```
const vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, 'xyz', {
  vpcId: 'vpc-****',
});

const securityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'uqt_api_db_sg', {
  vpc,
  securityGroupName: `xyz-${stage}`,
  description: `some-${stage}`,
});
securityGroup.addIngressRule(ec2.Peer.ipv4('******/**'), ec2.Port.tcp(5432));
securityGroup.addIngressRule(ec2.Peer.ipv4('0.0.0.0/0'), ec2.Port.tcp(443));
securityGroup.addIngressRule(ec2.Peer.ipv4('0.0.0.0/0'), ec2.Port.tcp(80));

const dbInstance = new rds.DatabaseInstance(this, 'uqt_api_db', {
  subnetGroup: rds.SubnetGroup.fromSubnetGroupName(this, 'rdssubnets', 'rdssubnets'),
  engine: rds.DatabaseInstanceEngine.postgres({
    version: rds.PostgresEngineVersion.VER_14_2,
  }),
  port: 5432,
  publiclyAccessible: false,
  securityGroups: [securityGroup],
  vpc: vpc,
  // ... some more config
});

const appRunnerVpcConnector = new aws_apprunner.CfnVpcConnector(this, 'AppRunnerVpcConnector', {
  subnets: vpc.selectSubnets({
    subnetType: SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_NAT,
  }).subnetIds,
  securityGroups: [securityGroup.securityGroupId],
  vpcConnectorName: 'AbcApiVpcConnector',
});

const appRunnerServiceRole = new iam.Role(this, 'AppRunnerServiceRole', {
  assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('build.apprunner.amazonaws.com'),
});

appRunnerServiceRole.addManagedPolicy(
  iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('service-role/AWSAppRunnerServicePolicyForECRAccess'),
);

const appRunnerInstanceRole = new iam.Role(this, 'AppRunnerInstanceRole', {
  assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('tasks.apprunner.amazonaws.com'),
});

const appRunnerService = new aws_apprunner.CfnService(this, 'AppRunnerVpcService', {
  sourceConfiguration: {
    autoDeploymentsEnabled: true,
    imageRepository: {
      imageRepositoryType: 'ECR',
      imageIdentifier: appRunnerContainerImage.imageUri,
      imageConfiguration: {
        port: '80',
        runtimeEnvironmentVariables: [
          {
            name: 'PORT',
            value: '80',
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    authenticationConfiguration: {
      accessRoleArn: appRunnerServiceRole.roleArn,
    },
  },
  networkConfiguration: {
    egressConfiguration: {
      egressType: 'VPC',
      vpcConnectorArn: appRunnerVpcConnector.attrVpcConnectorArn,
    },
  },
  serviceName: Stack.of(this).stackName,
  instanceConfiguration: {
    instanceRoleArn: appRunnerInstanceRole.roleArn,
  },
});

appRunnerService.node.addDependency(dbInstance);
```

Comment: Do you have a health check endpoint ("/health") in your application?

Comment: No, its a TCP health check at port 80

Comment: Don't suppose you figured this out?